# ENV["VARIABLE"].encoding return #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT> on production when being assigned a unicode string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, docker

I'm using ENV["VARIABLE"] inside my Rails app which being set to a unicode string.
On production (which is a docker container), this ENV["VARIABLE"] is somehow encoded with `Encoding:ASCII-8BIT` (though ENV["PWD"], for instance, is encoded with `Encoding:UTF-8`). On `development`, every variable is encoded with `Encoding:UTF-8`. The encoding of ASCII-8BIT prevent me to render the variable in a view. What is the cause? How could I fix?

Comment: Look like it's the problem with the docker Ubuntu image. I switch to CentOS and set LANG="en_US.UTF-8" inside the container then the issue goes away.